# What is a backlit CCD sensor, and why might I prefer it to other kinds?

Tags: optics, astronomy

I've heard Astronomers talking about backlit CCD sensors, and talking about how much better they are than other types. What are they, why might I want to get one, and what are the pros/cons of this compared to related technologies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A backlit sensor isn't really a new kind of sensor, it's just a different arrangement of the imaging elements to allow more light into the sensor. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-illuminated_sensor):

> A traditional digital camera sensor
>   consists of a matrix of individual
>   picture elements. Each element is
>   constructed in a fashion similar to
>   the human eye, with a lens at the
>   front, sensors at the back, and wiring
>   in between. The front of the detectors
>   require an active matrix to be placed
>   on their front surface. The matrix and
>   its wiring reflects or absorbs some of
>   the incoming light, thereby reducing
>   the signal that is available to be
>   captured.
>
> A back-illuminated sensor moves this
>   wiring behind the sensors, similar to
>   a Cephalopod eye.

They're not without issues though:

> Moving the active matrix transistors
>   to the back of the photosensitive
>   layer normally leads to a host of
>   problems, such as cross-talk, which
>   causes noise, dark current, and color
>   mixing between adjacent pixels.

Backlit sensors improve the low-light performance of a CCD chip, reducing the ISO needed for low-light conditions (and thus reducing noise). This is a clear benefit to astrophotographers, allowing them to use shorter exposures with less noise to get equivalent shots.

Comment: Back-illuminated CCDs also have their peak sensitivity shifted to a different wavelength- somewhat bluer, I think.